# Is 2048x1536 a Common Camera Resolution on Android Devices?

Tags: android, camera, resolution

My app is optimized for handling images with the size of 2048x1536. Am I safe to assume that most modern Android phones with at least a 5MP camera support this resolution?

I will not rely completely on the availability of this resolution, but I wanted to know if this is a good common denominator that covers most common devices.

Comment: It's true only for **modern** devices. But keep in mind  old and China phones

Comment: @ruX Old/china android phones? I wouldn't really keep those in mind for long :)

Comment: it should be fine, for example, the resolution on a galaxy nexus is `720x(1280 - 90)`. the -90 is for the small "menu-bar" at the bottom. But that dosnt really have to be taken into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No-contract Android phones are getting more popular, and you see these with 3 MP cameras. Most mid-end to high-end phones will have the higher megapixel count. By the way: 2048x1536 is a little over 3 MP.

It should be a pretty safe target. Just watch out for RAM allocation, especially before 3.0, since that uses about 9.4 megs of RAM as uncompressed RGB24

Comment: isn't an uncompressed bitmap of this resolution take : ~12MB , as 2048*1536*4 = 12,582,912 bytes ? Also, this has nothing to do with 3.0 version of Android... However, Android 3.0 helps a lot with bitmaps.

Comment: It's 3 bytes per pixel for RGB24, but I wouldn't be surprised if it someone decided to do 4 bytes per pixel in Android. If it were 4 bytes per pixel (RGB8888), it would be your value

Comment: Google recommends to never use this bitmap config (which is called ARGB_4444) , but you can use the one that FF uses, which use 2 bytes per pixel (RGB_565). It's usually barely noticeable, but the downside is that you'll miss transparency. The default configuration is 4 bytes per pixel (which is called ARGB_8888 ). Here's a link anyway: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html